# Undefined Behavior with Eigen Vector*Scalar + Vector*Scalar --> libigl/external/eigen and other eigen conflicts

Tags: c++, eigen3, address-sanitizer

I'm hunting down a weird runtime bug in my code that is consistent. I get what I think is undefined behavior on a line that looks like:
`Eigen::Vector3d m = d1 * cos(theta) + d2 * sin(theta)`
where d1 and d2 are are Vector3d and theta is a double.

If I reverse the order of operations I do not get the error, e.g.
`Eigen::Vector3d m = cos(theta) * d1 + sin(theta) * d2`

More confusing aspects:
1. I cannot replicate this error in a simple script so no minimum reproducible example yet :-\
I can only get this effect in my project, where of course there is a lot more going on.
2. My collaborator can compile and run the code just fine on her end both on her Windows and Mac machines.
3. This error only comes up with compiling in Debug mode. Compiling in Release does not trigger the error in the same place.

I've ran ASan and have the output and it seems clear that there is a memory access out of bounds, but ASan halts deep in the Eigen library (ASan output included).
I'm at a loss as where to go from here on this problem.

Thanks a bunch. I'm relatively new to C++, Eigen and ASan so if more info is needed please let me know.

MacOS 10.15.3
Clang 11.0.1
C++14

EDIT: To be clear, I don't think this is an Eigen Library problem, but rather I am trying to determine how the error is occurring and as of right now it looks like it finally triggers in the Eigen library. Any insight or explanations would be incredibly helpful!

```
==27180==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: stack-buffer-overflow on address 0x7ffee97dcef8 at pc 0x0001066d7773 bp 0x7ffee97dcac0 sp 0x7ffee97dcab8
WRITE of size 8 at 0x7ffee97dcef8 thread T0
    #0 0x1066d7772 in Eigen::internal::scalar_constant_op<double>::scalar_constant_op(Eigen::internal::scalar_constant_op<double> const&) NullaryFunctors.h:19
    #1 0x1066d7656 in Eigen::internal::scalar_constant_op<double>::scalar_constant_op(Eigen::internal::scalar_constant_op<double> const&) NullaryFunctors.h:19
    #2 0x1066dafa6 in Eigen::internal::evaluator<Eigen::CwiseNullaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_constant_op<double>, Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 1, 0, 3, 1> const> >::evaluator(Eigen::CwiseNullaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_constant_op<double>, Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 1, 0, 3, 1> const> const&) CoreEvaluators.h:473
    #3 0x1066dae9f in Eigen::internal::evaluator<Eigen::CwiseNullaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_constant_op<double>, Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 1, 0, 3, 1> const> const>::evaluator(Eigen::CwiseNullaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_constant_op<double>, Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 1, 0, 3, 1> const> const&) CoreEvaluators.h:103
    #4 0x1066d9fc6 in Eigen::internal::evaluator<Eigen::CwiseNullaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_constant_op<double>, Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 1, 0, 3, 1> const> const>::evaluator(Eigen::CwiseNullaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_constant_op<double>, Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 1, 0, 3, 1> const> const&) CoreEvaluators.h:103
    #5 0x1066da443 in Eigen::internal::binary_evaluator<Eigen::CwiseBinaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_product_op<double, double>, Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 1, 0, 3, 1> const, Eigen::CwiseNullaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_constant_op<double>, Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 1, 0, 3, 1> const> const>, Eigen::internal::IndexBased, Eigen::internal::IndexBased, double, double>::binary_evaluator(Eigen::CwiseBinaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_product_op<double, double>, Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 1, 0, 3, 1> const, Eigen::CwiseNullaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_constant_op<double>, Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 1, 0, 3, 1> const> const> const&) CoreEvaluators.h:702
    #6 0x1066da22f in Eigen::internal::evaluator<Eigen::CwiseBinaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_product_op<double, double>, Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 1, 0, 3, 1> const, Eigen::CwiseNullaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_constant_op<double>, Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 1, 0, 3, 1> const> const> >::evaluator(Eigen::CwiseBinaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_product_op<double, double>, Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 1, 0, 3, 1> const, Eigen::CwiseNullaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_constant_op<double>, Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 1, 0, 3, 1> const> const> const&) CoreEvaluators.h:671
    #7 0x1066da14f in Eigen::internal::evaluator<Eigen::CwiseBinaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_product_op<double, double>, Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 1, 0, 3, 1> const, Eigen::CwiseNullaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_constant_op<double>, Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 1, 0, 3, 1> const> const> const>::evaluator(Eigen::CwiseBinaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_product_op<double, double>, Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 1, 0, 3, 1> const, Eigen::CwiseNullaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_constant_op<double>, Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 1, 0, 3, 1> const> const> const&) CoreEvaluators.h:103
    #8 0x1066d9ec6 in Eigen::internal::evaluator<Eigen::CwiseBinaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_product_op<double, double>, Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 1, 0, 3, 1> const, Eigen::CwiseNullaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_constant_op<double>, Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 1, 0, 3, 1> const> const> const>::evaluator(Eigen::CwiseBinaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_product_op<double, double>, Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 1, 0, 3, 1> const, Eigen::CwiseNullaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_constant_op<double>, Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 1, 0, 3, 1> const> const> const&) CoreEvaluators.h:103
    #9 0x106ab3735 in Eigen::internal::binary_evaluator<Eigen::CwiseBinaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_sum_op<double, double>, Eigen::CwiseBinaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_product_op<double, double>, Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 1, 0, 3, 1> const, Eigen::CwiseNullaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_constant_op<double>, Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 1, 0, 3, 1> const> const> const, Eigen::CwiseBinaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_product_op<double, double>, Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 1, 0, 3, 1> const, Eigen::CwiseNullaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_constant_op<double>, Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 1, 0, 3, 1> const> const> const>, Eigen::internal::IndexBased, Eigen::internal::IndexBased, double, double>::Data::Data(Eigen::CwiseBinaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_sum_op<double, double>, Eigen::CwiseBinaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_product_op<double, double>, Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 1, 0, 3, 1> const, Eigen::CwiseNullaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_constant_op<double>, Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 1, 0, 3, 1> const> const> const, Eigen::CwiseBinaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_product_op<double, double>, Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 1, 0, 3, 1> const, Eigen::CwiseNullaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_constant_op<double>, Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 1, 0, 3, 1> const> const> const> const&) CoreEvaluators.h:799
    #10 0x106ab3506 in Eigen::internal::binary_evaluator<Eigen::CwiseBinaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_sum_op<double, double>, Eigen::CwiseBinaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_product_op<double, double>, Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 1, 0, 3, 1> const, Eigen::CwiseNullaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_constant_op<double>, Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 1, 0, 3, 1> const> const> const, Eigen::CwiseBinaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_product_op<double, double>, Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 1, 0, 3, 1> const, Eigen::CwiseNullaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_constant_op<double>, Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 1, 0, 3, 1> const> const> const>, Eigen::internal::IndexBased, Eigen::internal::IndexBased, double, double>::Data::Data(Eigen::CwiseBinaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_sum_op<double, double>, Eigen::CwiseBinaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_product_op<double, double>, Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 1, 0, 3, 1> const, Eigen::CwiseNullaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_constant_op<double>, Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 1, 0, 3, 1> const> const> const, Eigen::CwiseBinaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_product_op<double, double>, Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 1, 0, 3, 1> const, Eigen::CwiseNullaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_constant_op<double>, Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 1, 0, 3, 1> const> const> const> const&) CoreEvaluators.h:799
    #11 0x106ab343e in Eigen::internal::binary_evaluator<Eigen::CwiseBinaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_sum_op<double, double>, Eigen::CwiseBinaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_product_op<double, double>, Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 1, 0, 3, 1> const, Eigen::CwiseNullaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_constant_op<double>, Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 1, 0, 3, 1> const> const> const, Eigen::CwiseBinaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_product_op<double, double>, Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 1, 0, 3, 1> const, Eigen::CwiseNullaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_constant_op<double>, Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 1, 0, 3, 1> const> const> const>, Eigen::internal::IndexBased, Eigen::internal::IndexBased, double, double>::binary_evaluator(Eigen::CwiseBinaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_sum_op<double, double>, Eigen::CwiseBinaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_product_op<double, double>, Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 1, 0, 3, 1> const, Eigen::CwiseNullaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_constant_op<double>, Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 1, 0, 3, 1> const> const> const, Eigen::CwiseBinaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_product_op<double, double>, Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 1, 0, 3, 1> const, Eigen::CwiseNullaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_constant_op<double>, Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 1, 0, 3, 1> const> const> const> const&) CoreEvaluators.h:757
    #12 0x106ab336f in Eigen::internal::evaluator<Eigen::CwiseBinaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_sum_op<double, double>, Eigen::CwiseBinaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_product_op<double, double>, Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 1, 0, 3, 1> const, Eigen::CwiseNullaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_constant_op<double>, Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 1, 0, 3, 1> const> const> const, Eigen::CwiseBinaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_product_op<double, double>, Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 1, 0, 3, 1> const, Eigen::CwiseNullaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_constant_op<double>, Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 1, 0, 3, 1> const> const> const> >::evaluator(Eigen::CwiseBinaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_sum_op<double, double>, Eigen::CwiseBinaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_product_op<double, double>, Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 1, 0, 3, 1> const, Eigen::CwiseNullaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_constant_op<double>, Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 1, 0, 3, 1> const> const> const, Eigen::CwiseBinaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_product_op<double, double>, Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 1, 0, 3, 1> const, Eigen::CwiseNullaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_constant_op<double>, Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 1, 0, 3, 1> const> const> const> const&) CoreEvaluators.h:728
    #13 0x106ab2d96 in Eigen::internal::evaluator<Eigen::CwiseBinaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_sum_op<double, double>, Eigen::CwiseBinaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_product_op<double, double>, Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 1, 0, 3, 1> const, Eigen::CwiseNullaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_constant_op<double>, Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 1, 0, 3, 1> const> const> const, Eigen::CwiseBinaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_product_op<double, double>, Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 1, 0, 3, 1> const, Eigen::CwiseNullaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_constant_op<double>, Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 1, 0, 3, 1> const> const> const> >::evaluator(Eigen::CwiseBinaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_sum_op<double, double>, Eigen::CwiseBinaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_product_op<double, double>, Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 1, 0, 3, 1> const, Eigen::CwiseNullaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_constant_op<double>, Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 1, 0, 3, 1> const> const> const, Eigen::CwiseBinaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_product_op<double, double>, Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 1, 0, 3, 1> const, Eigen::CwiseNullaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_constant_op<double>, Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 1, 0, 3, 1> const> const> const> const&) CoreEvaluators.h:728
    #14 0x106ab2954 in void Eigen::internal::call_dense_assignment_loop<Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 1, 0, 3, 1>, Eigen::CwiseBinaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_sum_op<double, double>, Eigen::CwiseBinaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_product_op<double, double>, Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 1, 0, 3, 1> const, Eigen::CwiseNullaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_constant_op<double>, Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 1, 0, 3, 1> const> const> const, Eigen::CwiseBinaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_product_op<double, double>, Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 1, 0, 3, 1> const, Eigen::CwiseNullaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_constant_op<double>, Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 1, 0, 3, 1> const> const> const>, Eigen::internal::assign_op<double, double> >(Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 1, 0, 3, 1>&, Eigen::CwiseBinaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_sum_op<double, double>, Eigen::CwiseBinaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_product_op<double, double>, Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 1, 0, 3, 1> const, Eigen::CwiseNullaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_constant_op<double>, Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 1, 0, 3, 1> const> const> const, Eigen::CwiseBinaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_product_op<double, double>, Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 1, 0, 3, 1> const, Eigen::CwiseNullaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_constant_op<double>, Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 1, 0, 3, 1> const> const> const> const&, Eigen::internal::assign_op<double, double> const&) AssignEvaluator.h:756
    #15 0x106ab274c in Eigen::internal::Assignment<Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 1, 0, 3, 1>, Eigen::CwiseBinaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_sum_op<double, double>, Eigen::CwiseBinaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_product_op<double, double>, Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 1, 0, 3, 1> const, Eigen::CwiseNullaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_constant_op<double>, Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 1, 0, 3, 1> const> const> const, Eigen::CwiseBinaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_product_op<double, double>, Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 1, 0, 3, 1> const, Eigen::CwiseNullaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_constant_op<double>, Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 1, 0, 3, 1> const> const> const>, Eigen::internal::assign_op<double, double>, Eigen::internal::Dense2Dense, void>::run(Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 1, 0, 3, 1>&, Eigen::CwiseBinaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_sum_op<double, double>, Eigen::CwiseBinaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_product_op<double, double>, Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 1, 0, 3, 1> const, Eigen::CwiseNullaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_constant_op<double>, Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 1, 0, 3, 1> const> const> const, Eigen::CwiseBinaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_product_op<double, double>, Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 1, 0, 3, 1> const, Eigen::CwiseNullaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_constant_op<double>, Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 1, 0, 3, 1> const> const> const> const&, Eigen::internal::assign_op<double, double> const&) AssignEvaluator.h:926
    #16 0x106ab25ed in void Eigen::internal::call_assignment_no_alias<Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 1, 0, 3, 1>, Eigen::CwiseBinaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_sum_op<double, double>, Eigen::CwiseBinaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_product_op<double, double>, Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 1, 0, 3, 1> const, Eigen::CwiseNullaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_constant_op<double>, Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 1, 0, 3, 1> const> const> const, Eigen::CwiseBinaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_product_op<double, double>, Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 1, 0, 3, 1> const, Eigen::CwiseNullaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_constant_op<double>, Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 1, 0, 3, 1> const> const> const>, Eigen::internal::assign_op<double, double> >(Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 1, 0, 3, 1>&, Eigen::CwiseBinaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_sum_op<double, double>, Eigen::CwiseBinaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_product_op<double, double>, Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 1, 0, 3, 1> const, Eigen::CwiseNullaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_constant_op<double>, Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 1, 0, 3, 1> const> const> const, Eigen::CwiseBinaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_product_op<double, double>, Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 1, 0, 3, 1> const, Eigen::CwiseNullaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_constant_op<double>, Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 1, 0, 3, 1> const> const> const> const&, Eigen::internal::assign_op<double, double> const&) AssignEvaluator.h:862
    #17 0x106ab22b3 in Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 1, 0, 3, 1>& Eigen::PlainObjectBase<Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 1, 0, 3, 1> >::_set_noalias<Eigen::CwiseBinaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_sum_op<double, double>, Eigen::CwiseBinaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_product_op<double, double>, Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 1, 0, 3, 1> const, Eigen::CwiseNullaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_constant_op<double>, Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 1, 0, 3, 1> const> const> const, Eigen::CwiseBinaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_product_op<double, double>, Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 1, 0, 3, 1> const, Eigen::CwiseNullaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_constant_op<double>, Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 1, 0, 3, 1> const> const> const> >(Eigen::DenseBase<Eigen::CwiseBinaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_sum_op<double, double>, Eigen::CwiseBinaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_product_op<double, double>, Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 1, 0, 3, 1> const, Eigen::CwiseNullaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_constant_op<double>, Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 1, 0, 3, 1> const> const> const, Eigen::CwiseBinaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_product_op<double, double>, Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 1, 0, 3, 1> const, Eigen::CwiseNullaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_constant_op<double>, Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 1, 0, 3, 1> const> const> const> > const&) PlainObjectBase.h:797
    #18 0x106ab1db9 in Eigen::PlainObjectBase<Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 1, 0, 3, 1> >::PlainObjectBase<Eigen::CwiseBinaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_sum_op<double, double>, Eigen::CwiseBinaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_product_op<double, double>, Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 1, 0, 3, 1> const, Eigen::CwiseNullaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_constant_op<double>, Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 1, 0, 3, 1> const> const> const, Eigen::CwiseBinaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_product_op<double, double>, Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 1, 0, 3, 1> const, Eigen::CwiseNullaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_constant_op<double>, Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 1, 0, 3, 1> const> const> const> >(Eigen::DenseBase<Eigen::CwiseBinaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_sum_op<double, double>, Eigen::CwiseBinaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_product_op<double, double>, Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 1, 0, 3, 1> const, Eigen::CwiseNullaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_constant_op<double>, Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 1, 0, 3, 1> const> const> const, Eigen::CwiseBinaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_product_op<double, double>, Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 1, 0, 3, 1> const, Eigen::CwiseNullaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_constant_op<double>, Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 1, 0, 3, 1> const> const> const> > const&) PlainObjectBase.h:602
    #19 0x106ab1c18 in Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 1, 0, 3, 1>::Matrix<Eigen::CwiseBinaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_sum_op<double, double>, Eigen::CwiseBinaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_product_op<double, double>, Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 1, 0, 3, 1> const, Eigen::CwiseNullaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_constant_op<double>, Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 1, 0, 3, 1> const> const> const, Eigen::CwiseBinaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_product_op<double, double>, Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 1, 0, 3, 1> const, Eigen::CwiseNullaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_constant_op<double>, Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 1, 0, 3, 1> const> const> const> >(Eigen::EigenBase<Eigen::CwiseBinaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_sum_op<double, double>, Eigen::CwiseBinaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_product_op<double, double>, Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 1, 0, 3, 1> const, Eigen::CwiseNullaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_constant_op<double>, Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 1, 0, 3, 1> const> const> const, Eigen::CwiseBinaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_product_op<double, double>, Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 1, 0, 3, 1> const, Eigen::CwiseNullaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_constant_op<double>, Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 1, 0, 3, 1> const> const> const> > const&) Matrix.h:423
    #20 0x106a5f606 in Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 1, 0, 3, 1>::Matrix<Eigen::CwiseBinaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_sum_op<double, double>, Eigen::CwiseBinaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_product_op<double, double>, Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 1, 0, 3, 1> const, Eigen::CwiseNullaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_constant_op<double>, Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 1, 0, 3, 1> const> const> const, Eigen::CwiseBinaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_product_op<double, double>, Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 1, 0, 3, 1> const, Eigen::CwiseNullaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_constant_op<double>, Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 1, 0, 3, 1> const> const> const> >(Eigen::EigenBase<Eigen::CwiseBinaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_sum_op<double, double>, Eigen::CwiseBinaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_product_op<double, double>, Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 1, 0, 3, 1> const, Eigen::CwiseNullaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_constant_op<double>, Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 1, 0, 3, 1> const> const> const, Eigen::CwiseBinaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_product_op<double, double>, Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 1, 0, 3, 1> const, Eigen::CwiseNullaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_constant_op<double>, Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 1, 0, 3, 1> const> const> const> > const&) Matrix.h:424
    #21 0x106a5ad6c in ElasticRods::ElasticRod::initialize_rest_quantities() ElasticRod.cpp:84
    #22 0x106b612b1 in ElasticRods::ElasticRod::ElasticRod(ElasticRods::RodState const&, ElasticRods::RodState const&, ElasticRods::RodParams const&, Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, 1, 0, -1, 1> const&) ElasticRod.h:164
    #23 0x106b286d0 in ElasticRods::ElasticRod::ElasticRod(ElasticRods::RodState const&, ElasticRods::RodState const&, ElasticRods::RodParams const&, Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, 1, 0, -1, 1> const&) ElasticRod.h:162
    #24 0x106b2b88a in ElasticRods::read_config_from(char const*, bool) RodConfiguration.cpp:110
    #25 0x106c9d14c in ElasticRods::RodsSim::init_simulation() RodsSim.cpp:170
    #26 0x10691141b in ElasticRods::PhysicsSim::reset() PhysicsSim.h:96
    #27 0x10642904c in main::$_3::operator()() const main.cpp:52
    #28 0x106426a26 in main main.cpp:137
    #29 0x7fff73bd87fc in start (libdyld.dylib:x86_64+0x1a7fc)

Address 0x7ffee97dcef8 is located in stack of thread T0 at offset 88 in frame
    #0 0x106ab278f in void Eigen::internal::call_dense_assignment_loop<Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 1, 0, 3, 1>, Eigen::CwiseBinaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_sum_op<double, double>, Eigen::CwiseBinaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_product_op<double, double>, Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 1, 0, 3, 1> const, Eigen::CwiseNullaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_constant_op<double>, Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 1, 0, 3, 1> const> const> const, Eigen::CwiseBinaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_product_op<double, double>, Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 1, 0, 3, 1> const, Eigen::CwiseNullaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_constant_op<double>, Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 1, 0, 3, 1> const> const> const>, Eigen::internal::assign_op<double, double> >(Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 1, 0, 3, 1>&, Eigen::CwiseBinaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_sum_op<double, double>, Eigen::CwiseBinaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_product_op<double, double>, Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 1, 0, 3, 1> const, Eigen::CwiseNullaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_constant_op<double>, Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 1, 0, 3, 1> const> const> const, Eigen::CwiseBinaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_product_op<double, double>, Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 1, 0, 3, 1> const, Eigen::CwiseNullaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_constant_op<double>, Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 1, 0, 3, 1> const> const> const> const&, Eigen::internal::assign_op<double, double> const&) AssignEvaluator.h:752

  This frame has 3 object(s):
    [32, 88) 'srcEvaluator' (line 756) <== Memory access at offset 88 overflows this variable
    [128, 136) 'dstEvaluator' (line 762)
    [160, 192) 'kernel' (line 765)
HINT: this may be a false positive if your program uses some custom stack unwind mechanism, swapcontext or vfork
      (longjmp and C++ exceptions *are* supported)
SUMMARY: AddressSanitizer: stack-buffer-overflow NullaryFunctors.h:19 in Eigen::internal::scalar_constant_op<double>::scalar_constant_op(Eigen::internal::scalar_constant_op<double> const&)
Shadow bytes around the buggy address:
  0x1fffdd2fb980: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  0x1fffdd2fb990: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  0x1fffdd2fb9a0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  0x1fffdd2fb9b0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  0x1fffdd2fb9c0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
=>0x1fffdd2fb9d0: 00 00 00 00 f1 f1 f1 f1 00 00 00 00 00 00 00[f2]
  0x1fffdd2fb9e0: f2 f2 f2 f2 f8 f2 f2 f2 f8 f8 f8 f8 f3 f3 f3 f3
  0x1fffdd2fb9f0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  0x1fffdd2fba00: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  0x1fffdd2fba10: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  0x1fffdd2fba20: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 f1 f1 f1 f1
Shadow byte legend (one shadow byte represents 8 application bytes):
  Addressable:           00
  Partially addressable: 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 
  Heap left redzone:       fa
  Freed heap region:       fd
  Stack left redzone:      f1
  Stack mid redzone:       f2
  Stack right redzone:     f3
  Stack after return:      f5
  Stack use after scope:   f8
  Global redzone:          f9
  Global init order:       f6
  Poisoned by user:        f7
  Container overflow:      fc
  Array cookie:            ac
  Intra object redzone:    bb
  ASan internal:           fe
  Left alloca redzone:     ca
  Right alloca redzone:    cb
  Shadow gap:              cc
==27180==ABORTING
```

EDIT: Edited title to make this more findable for newbies like myself that aren't sure where things are going wrong.

Comment: Given your statement that you can't provide a [mcve] that exhibits the problem, I'd bet against your claim that the problem is deep in the eigen library.   More likely, that some of your code is doing something wrong, and the consequence happens to be messing up memory that is later used in the eigen library. If you find that removing some code eliminates or changes the symptom, it's a fair bet that the removed code is a contributor to the problem.  Ignoring that because of an ASSUMPTION that the problem is in eigen (i.e. not in your code) means you may never find the cause(s) of the problem.

Comment: Very fair point @Peter. I should be more careful in my wording. When I said it's "in the Eigen library" what I should have said is, "ASan halts in the Eigen library". I certainly am not experienced enough to know where it is coming from. I'm just chasing down leads and trying to learn the right phrasing for describing my problem. Thanks for your input!

Comment: I don't think anyone here can help. Things you might try: [1](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicPitfalls.html), [2](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TopicStructHavingEigenMembers.html), [3](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TopicStlContainers.html). [4](https://github.com/ethz-asl/eigen_catkin/wiki/Eigen-Memory-Issues); Be sure you don't mix Eigen versions, run your code with valgrind.

Comment: Out of curiosity, can you try removing line 19 from `Eigen/src/Core/functors/NullaryFunctors.h`? This looks like a redundant copy constructor to me (though there is nothing wrong with that implementation, i.e., it should not cause by itself). Also, can you try the master branch of Eigen?

Comment: @chtz I am on master and commented out line 19 of NullaryFunctor.h. Rebuilt but it did not seem to alter the behavior

Comment: @pptaszni I spent a while making sure this isn't a vectorization or aliasing issue, but I can always check again. Also, from what I understand Asan is as good at rooting out these issues as valgrind. Is that a fair assessment?

Comment: If you were on master, [line 473 of CoreEvaluators.h](https://gitlab.com/libeigen/eigen/-/blob/master/Eigen/src/Core/CoreEvaluators.h#L473) should not appear in the stacktrace. Also, removing line 19 from NullaryFunctor.h should at least modify the first lines of your stacktrace.

Comment: @DanielRevier, yup it's fair. The bug seems to be difficult to investigate. I can only add that from my experience it is easy to accidentally mix Eigen versions (e.g. when using other libraries that use Eigen shipped with them implicitly).

Comment: @pptaszni oh wow I hadn't considered that option. I'm also using libigl and I know it's closely linked to Eigen, unsure if it's got its own copy though. I'll double check.

Comment: @chtz You're 100% right line 473 is commented out in that link so it shouldn't appear. It's also commented out in my version too though... I'll have to see if I've got another version floating around somehow and do a search for the CoreEvaluators.h

Comment: @chtz @pptaszni Further investigation revealed that libigl has it's own [Eigen library that gets downloaded with cmake](https://github.com/libigl/libigl/blob/87b54fc4dcc5aea182dd842a55ac75536fb69e1a/cmake/LibiglDownloadExternal.cmake#L70). Doing a `diff` on the `CoreEvaluators.h` between the newest gitlab pull of Eigen and the libigl/external Eigen (that I have) showed that they are different. I will have to see if it's as simple as making these Eigen libraries match exactly.

Comment: @chtz and pptaszni Both of your comments really helped. Turns out that libigl went and sneakily downloaded its own version of Eigen based off the 3.3.7 tag so that when I pulled the master for myself I was getting mixed Eigen libraries. I hadn't considered that libigl would use its own Eigen library so I hadn't considered that I could have mixed Eigen libraries, but checking out 3.3.7 for myself seems to have fixed the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Conversation in the comment thread really helped. Many thanks to @chtz and @pptaszni.

**tl;dr** When using `libigl`, make sure your `libigl/external/eigen` and any other `Eigen`s you reference match **exactly**.

**Answer**: An additional fact that I did not mention is that I am also using `libigl` in this project. It turns out that `libigl` pulls its own copy of the `Eigen` library, making it very easy to have conflicting/mixed `Eigen` libraries. I checked out the corresponding version of `Eigen` for myself that matches the version `libigl` pulled (in this case `tag 3.3.7`) and my issues seem to have been resolved.

**EDIT:** Expanding my thought process...
As chtz pointed out, if I was on master I wouldn't have seen the line 473 of `CoreEvaluators.h` in the stacktrace. I went and confirmed that I was on master (I was) and that line 473 of `CoreEvaluators.h` was indeed commented out (it was).

This led me to think about what pptaszni said and how other libraries can have conflicting versions of Eigen. The only other library I was referencing was `libigl`, so I did a fuzzy find for `CoreEvaluators.h` and it turned out there was one tucked inside `libigl/external/eigen`. A diff of this file with the one from before showed they were indeed different.

Going into the `libigl/external/eigen` directory showed me what branch `libigl` had checked out (`tag 3.3.7`). I then went to my personal `Eigen` library and checked out the same tag, recompiled and my weird runtime issue cleared up.